# DataGrip navigation bar 'enter' hit opens console instead of expanding folder

Tags: datagrip

I press cmd + up to navigate in datagrip. When I find schema I want to explore, after I hit enter it opens console instead of expanding schema contents to the right. How can i expand schema?

[image]

Comment: To navigate you need to use the Database Explorer on the left

Comment: Nah..There must be a better way. What is the point of cmd + up in DataGrip then? in PyCharm it works as expected.....please fix

Comment: @IamMashed I filed an issue based on your description https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13363 . Upvote and follow.